# Angular Material - Grid layout not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, materialize

I'm trying to use the Materialize grid layout in my Angular 7 project with Angular Materia but it does not work. This piece of code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s10">
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>Fill the next fields in order to sign in.</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is being displayed with a 100% width. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Haven't used Materialize, but I would guess that there are [conflicting styles with Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174290/angular-material-and-materializecss-collision)

Comment: Is the `<div class="container">` being displayed with 100% width? What is it inside of? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: The expected behaviour is the card being displayed with a 10 column width.

Comment: Got the problem. Angular Material uses the GridList module to adchieve this behaviour. But it is not that good i must say.